# What timezone formats are there?

Tags: timezone

What timezone formats exists on UNIX systems? Can someone gather them in a short answer? How can I recognize them?

Comment: In what context?

Comment: olson, posix, what else?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in the first place? Leave time zone parsing up to existing code. It's somewhat system-specfific, and time is a very deep and broad subject. If you implement whatever algorithm you're attempting based on a short answer, you will get the algorithm wrong, guaranteed. You will miss some corner case somewhere, which someone else has already covered in the existing code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Time zone data in modern UNIX systems comes from the public-domain [IANA Time Zone Database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones).  This database is what provides the timezone names, and the complex and ever-changing rules for timezones themselves.  [Wikipedia has a good overview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) of the database and the various formats in which it can be found, and includes a [list of timezones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) from that database.

Comment: I'm searching for timezone FORMATS, not timezones, ex.: OLSON, POSIX

Comment: Well, you just named them both. POSIX is insufficient to describe zones fully, and Olson is the guy who made the database I just mentioned.  Everyone should use the Olson names from the tz database these days.

Comment: By the way, the tz database also includes the POSIX names under the "SystemV" prefix.